# Binomial or permutation probability?

Tags: probability

A bowl contains 20 white balls, 10 red balls, and 10 blue balls.  Assuming replacement, what is the probability you draw three red balls in a row?

Comment: Can you see the balls before you draw them? Are some of the balls bigger than others? Do you get a bonus for picking three red ones? Are you allowed to stick something onto a ball before replacing it?

Comment: @Gerry, please tell me youre joking.

Comment: @Sally, I think you are getting combinatorics and probability confused. They are related but different.  At the simplest, you can answer this with Bayesian principles.

Comment: @Cogito, polls predicted Landon would beat Roosevelt in the 1936 election. Roosevelt won in a landslide. Turned out the poll was conducted by telephone, and in 1936 people who owned telephones were not a representative sampling of the population. It pays to make sure there aren't any hidden assumptions in an applied problem such as this, and it's important to make students aware of them.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: Here are what I think Gerry Myerson intended: "Can you see the balls before you draw them? Are some of the balls bigger than others? Do you get a bonus for picking three red ones?" These ask **is the choice of one ball is as likely as any another?** "Are you allowed to stick something onto a ball before replacing it?" This asks **is the choice of one ball independent of the choice of the previous balls?** *I* would have asked differently, but the question *is* terse and shows no effort by the OP. However, personal attacks and insults are not necessary or welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The probability assuming replacement is $\frac{10}{20+10+10}\times\frac{10}{20+10+10}\times\frac{10}{20+10+10}$.

Comment: There is something to be said for leaving some work for OP, when it's a homework problem.